# Is there a way to compare bundle identifiers without using a hardcoded string?

Tags: swift

I'm working on a project where we have two different app versions that are being handled as different targets, both apps are very similar but they differ in some screens that have different elements. So we are retrieving the app bundle identifier and comparing it with a hardcoded string to decide the flows, I need help finding a way to avoid using a hardcoded value for the string that is used for comparison with the bundle identifier.

This is how we are retrieving the bundle identifier:

```
var appName: String { return stringValue(for: kCFBundleNameKey) }
```

This is how we are getting the target:

```
var currentTarget: Target {
      return appName == "AppNumber1" ? .appnumber1 : .appnumber2
}
```

Target is an enum with 2 cases:

```
enum Target {
   case appnumber1
   case appnumber2
}
```

So what I would like to do is to avoid using the hardcoded string "AppNumber1" to compare with the bundle identifier. Is there any alternative?

Comment: You, normally, don't need to do something like this... Share all the shared code among targets and then add specific code files to appropriate targets. Each target has its own dependencies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Xcode 10.3, you can define a unique `Active Compilation Condition` for each target (`APPNUMBER1`, `APPNUMBER2`) and then you can check in code what target is currently running. An example is shown below.

```
#if APPNUMBER1
//Code for "AppNumber1"
#elseif APPNUMBER2
//Code for "AppNumber2"
#endif
```